# KonvaJS - No transformer update after group.clip()

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

### About the issue

I'm working on a graphics editor built with [konva.js](https://konvajs.org)
After hours of research, I cannot get the [transformer](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Transformer.html) to adjust to the clipped size of a [group](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Group.html)

### Details

I have a group that defines a [simple clip](https://konvajs.org/docs/clipping/Clipping_Regions.html) area, and within this there are 2 [rectangles](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Rect.html) of the exact same size and position, stacked on top of each other.

- the bottom rectangle is [filled with an image](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Rect.html#fillPatternImage__anchor)
- the top rectangle is [filled with rgba colour](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Rect.html#fill__anchor)

The clipped group works well; however, this application is dynamic, so, it takes input from the user to set a clip area. When I call `group.clip()` and `layer.batchDraw()` it does the clipping, but the bounding rectangle (transformer) does not update, even after I call `transformer.forceUpdate()` on it, no luck.

### What I've tried

When I `destroy` the transformer and re-create it, it still indicates the full-size (not the clipped size) and the clipped-off region still remains.

Here's a screen-shot for clarity:
[Screenshot-20191008-153503.png](https://postimg.cc/Tym0HdDf)

### Some code

I doubt if this would even help, the code is in separate files and the values come from user-input as mentioned. For what it's worth, this is for you:

```
let grp = new Konva.Group({x:o.x,y:o.y,draggable:o.draggable,clip:{x:0,y:0,width:o.width,height:o.height}});
```

Any other code I paste here will just confuse the hect out of us all, it's A LOT, and I know people run when they see that, so, if I should add more code, please let me know in the comments?

I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [lavtron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512042/lavrton)'s answer could work, a more direct approach solves the issue:

### Bug Patch

```
(function()
{
    let func = Konva.Group.prototype.getClientRect;
    let orig = {enumerable:false, configurable:false, writable:false, value:func};
    let altr = {enumerable:false, configurable:false, writable:false, value:function(t)
    {
        let attr = this.attrs;
        let resl = this.getOrigClientRect(t);
        if(attr.hasOwnProperty('clipWidth')){resl.width=attr.clipWidth};
        if(attr.hasOwnProperty('clipHeight')){resl.height=attr.clipHeight};
        return resl;
    }};
    Object.defineProperty(Konva.Group.prototype,'getOrigClientRect', orig);
    Object.defineProperty(Konva.Group.prototype,'getClientRect', altr);
})();
```

### How to implement

To implement this patch:

- either add this in your own JavaScript - after the `konva.js` script loaded in the DOM,
- or paste this directly into the konva.js source

If you're using `RequireJS` to load KonvaJS, you should name your imported object accordingly and/or update the code above, -OR- just keep it as `Konva` (note the uppercase K).

### Technical details

This works by using the original `getClientRect` method's result and updating it with the `clipWidth` and `clipHeight` of the clipped-group - only if it has these attributes; else it returns the result unmodified.

This is tested and works well; however, it would be better if the the distribution source code of the konva.js repository could be updated accordingly.

Comment: Wow - why didn't I think of that! hehe - you are brilliant mister, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for the current moment with `konva@4.0.13`, `Konva.Transformer` doesn't support clipping. It just doesn't know about it so you see it in the "old" place.

The tricky workaround is:

1. Create a transparent rectangle with the size of the clipped area
2. Attach `Konva.Transformer` into that rectangle.
3. On `transform` or `transformend` events resize group or its children manually.